# Why is display=grid not working in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, grid, css-grid

I am using `display = grid` in CSS. It's works fine for Chrome & Firefox, but it's not working on IE. Any CSS tricks or any other solution?

Comment: In what version of IE?

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: `display:grid` is only working in IE11

Comment: Only in IE11 and only an older version of the spec. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Answer (score 4):

Specifying e.g.:

```
#grid_container {
    display: -ms-grid
    display: grid
    ...
}
<div id="grid_container">
    ...
</div>
```

will currently, as of 2017-11-14, work for Internet Explorer and Edge on Windows, as well as other browsers in Windows and other platforms.

The new style [display property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/) will take effect for other browsers, and the original [Grid element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-grid-layout-20120322/#grid-element) with the [vendor prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)  from the [March 2012 W3 Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-grid-layout-20120322/) will be used by Internet Explorer and Edge browsers in Windows.

This is current as of: 
2017-11-14:
IE 11.726.15063.0 Update 11.0.48
Edge 40.15063.674.0​
Windows 1703 Build 15063.726.

and tested in:
Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Vivaldi in High Sierra;
Chrome, Firefox, and Samsung Cloud (mobile browser) in an Android phone; and
Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Edge in Windows 10.

I am also still using e.g.:

```
-ms-grid-column: 2;
-ms-grid-column-span: 1;
-ms-grid-row: 1;
grid-column: 2 / 3;
grid-row: 1;
```

per prior research, i.e. [Rachel Andrew](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout/)

I realize this is a little old given the pace of things, but I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

**display: -ms-grid; for a** block-level Grid element

**display: -ms-inline-grid;** for a inline-level Grid element

from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673533(v=vs.85).aspx

The basic building block of Grid Layout is the Grid element, which is declared by setting the display property of an element to either -ms-grid (for a block-level Grid element) or -ms-inline-grid (for an inline-level Grid element). (Because of the preliminary status of the Grid Layout draft, this value and all the properties in this section must be used with the Microsoft-specific vendor prefix, "-ms-", to work with Internet Explorer 10 and Windows Store apps using JavaScript in Windows 8.)

Answer (score 0):

`display: grid` doesn't worked for me even in IE11. I replaced it with `display: block` and it worked in all browsers. Not sure if it will work in all scenarios. There were some alignment issues which I fixed using CSS.